# Linux pipe and sigaction

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I've got some code where I'm catching SIGIO signal. I wanted to write application which will be informed about arriving data to pipe. I intentionally didn't want to do it using select() function.
Here is the code:

```
void handler (int x)
{
    int fd, st;
    char buf[32];
    printf("signal_entry\n");
    fd = open("/tmp/pipe",  O_RDWR);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    st = read(fd, buf, 32);
    printf("st: %d  buf: %s\n", st, buf);
    close(fd);
    printf("signal_exit\n\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    int fd, sf, fl, st, num;
    struct stat sb;

    fd = open("/tmp/pipe", O_RDWR);
    memset(&act1, 0, sizeof(act1));
    sigfillset(&act1.sa_mask);
    act1.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGIO, &act1, NULL);
    sf = fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    fl = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fl | O_ASYNC);
    while (1) {
        printf("x\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

After run it shows "x" letter every 1 second. Then I write something into the pipe /tmp/pipe:

```
echo "bla" > /tmp/pipe.
```

The reaction of the program is that it reads data (string "bla") from pipe and shows its contents - and this is ok.

The problem is that the application invokes once again the my SIGIO handler and again. I mean the "handler" proc is infinitely called, so "while" loop in main() proc is not running anymore.

Why this effect occures? Did I miss anything? I thought that "handler" will be called only once per "echo" invocation...

Comment: `printf()` is not async-signal-safe and can't safely be called in a signal handler.  And you also treat what you `read()` as a NUL-terminated string, but you don't guarantee that it's actually NUL-terminated.

Comment: I've already tested this application without printf() in handler - and the problem still occured.

Comment: Why do you open the pipe twice? Do you still get the problem if you re-use `fd` from `main` in your handler, since that is the file descriptor that has generated the SIGIO.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code and now I'm re-using "fd" but the problem still occures.

Comment: You're really do to much in your signal handler. A signal handler should preferably only set a flag that you then check in your main loop. And if set then you clear it and do the work needed. That will also solve the signal-unsafe-function problem you have. And generally make your code simpler and safer.

Comment: If, in `main`, you open the named pipe read-only instead of read-write, do you still get endless signals?

Comment: Then the open() is opened in blocking mode so the program hangs on it and waits for any data from pipe. If then I put some data into pipe - the program starts writing "x", but the handler is not called. I must send some data second time to call the SIGIO handler. The fact is there is no endless signal - and any next data are fetched properly.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're trying to make things way more complicated for yourself by not using `select`?

Comment: I was hoping that using sigaction() is simplier way to do this instead of using select(). I'm trying to write the simplest code for someone who needs to integrate it in his app. This app already has a lot of threads and I'm afraid that using select() would need new thread especially for this function.

Answer (score 1):

After your `echo`-command terminates, the pipe you opened in "main" is EOF, so it will constantly trigger a SIGIO-event (namely, EOF on the pipe).
So you will have to re-open the pipe in the main function to get it working again.

It serves no purpose to reopen the pipe in the handler, however. Just use the fd from the `open()`-call in `main()`.

Comment: But when I reopen the pipe in the main proc I will have to register SIGIO handler again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved the problem.

Following change in main() is needed:

```
fd = open("/tmp/pipe", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

And of course open() from handler() should be removed.
Now it works properly.